# reading CUDA buffer in directx12

Tags: cuda, directx-12

after creating a GPU buffer in CUDA then exporting it using `cuMemExportToShareableHandle()` and getting a `HANDLE` then using the CUDA `HANDLE` as input in `ID3D12Device::OpenSharedHandle()` then fails with `Access violation writing location`can

(A)`OpenSharedHandle()` open CUDA handles or

(B)`OpenSharedHandle()` only opens handles created by `CreateSharedHandle()`
if it's (A) then there is something wrong with my handle
if it's (B) then is there another way to import the CUDA handle into directx12?

Answer (score 1):

I asked on the official directx discord
`OpenSharedHandle()` can only open directx handles
but a handle created by directx12 `CreateSharedHandle()` can be open by CUDA `cuMemImportFromShareableHandle()`